# How to delete content inside of a s3 bucket folders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am running a Lambda function to query access logs from ALB and send the output to an S3 bucket. Two queries are being executed:

```
Daily Logs
Monthly Logs
```

I have created one bucket and two folders, namely DailyLogs and MonthlyLogs, so that when the Lambda function is executed, the logs will be stored in their respective folders.

I have also added a function to delete the previous CSV file inside the logs and replace it with the new logs when generated. However, when the Lambda function is executed, the entire folders DailyLogs and MonthlyLogs are being deleted.

I only want the content inside the folders to be deleted and replaced by the new logs.

Can you please help me?

Attached is the Lambda code.

```
import boto3
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Query string to execute
daily_query = "SELECT * FROM \"DATABASE\".\"TABLE\" WHERE user_agent LIKE '%test%' AND date_parse(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') >= date_parse(date_format(date_add('day', -1, current_date), '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND date_parse(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') < date_parse(date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY time ASC"
monthly_query = "SELECT * FROM \"DATABASE\".\"TABLE\" WHERE parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') BETWEEN parse_datetime(CAST(date_trunc('month', current_date) AS varchar), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND parse_datetime(CAST(current_date AS varchar), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND user_agent LIKE '%test%' ORDER BY time ASC"

# Database to execute the query against
DATABASE = 'DATABASE'

# Output bucket
bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'

# Initialize Boto3 clients
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
athena_client = boto3.client('athena')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Get current date
        current_date = datetime.now()

        # Create folder names for daily and monthly logs
        daily_folder = f"DailyLogs/{current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}/"
        monthly_folder = f"MonthlyLogs/{current_date.strftime('%Y-%m')}/"

        # Delete existing files in the S3 bucket
        delete_daily_files(daily_folder)
        delete_monthly_files(monthly_folder)

        # Start the query executions
        response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=daily_query,
            QueryExecutionContext={'Database': DATABASE},
            ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': f's3://{bucket_name}/{daily_folder}'}
        )

        response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=monthly_query,
            QueryExecutionContext={'Database': DATABASE},
            ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': f's3://{bucket_name}/{monthly_folder}'}
        )

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return {'statusCode': 500, 'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})}

def delete_daily_files(folder):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder)
    if 'Contents' in response:
        keys_to_delete = [{'Key': obj['Key']} for obj in response['Contents']]
        if keys_to_delete:
            s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Delete={'Objects': keys_to_delete})

def delete_monthly_files(folder):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder)
    if 'Contents' in response:
        keys_to_delete = [{'Key': obj['Key']} for obj in response['Contents']]
        if keys_to_delete:
            s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Delete={'Objects': keys_to_delete})
```

Find the code attached. Instead of the files being deleted, the entire folders are getting deleted.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to retain the empty 'folder'? Typically you don't need, or want, to do this but if you do then you will need to create an S3 object to represent the folder e.g. upload a zero-sized object to the key `DailyLogs/2024-01-01/` (note the trailing forward slash).

Comment: You may want to look into partition projections. They allow athena to query multiple S3 objects as if they were a single table.  You can say something like `select * from dailylogs where '2024-01-01' <= dt and dt < '2024-02-01'`, and athena will figure out what S3 prefixes/objects it needs to look at. AWS service logs (like your ALB) are especially well suited for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html#partition-projection-using

Answer (score -1):

S3 buckets don't have "folders". They only contain files, aka "objects", and each object has a unique key which is *the entire filename*.

You can limit operations (like listing files) to a specific prefix string. For example, consider a bucket with the following contents:

```
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-1.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-2.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-3.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-1.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-2.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-3.txt
```

We can ask for files contained in the `2024-03-24` like this (as you do in your code):

```
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix="DailyLogs/2024-03-24")
```

And get back the list of objects:

```
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-1.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-2.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-3.txt
```

But the argument to "Prefix" doesn't need to be a "folder"; we can just as easily do:

```
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix="DailyL")
```

Which will return:

```
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-1.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-2.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-23/file-3.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-1.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-2.txt
DailyLogs/2024-03-24/file-3.txt
```

In other words, the argument to `Prefix` is just an arbitrary string, and the names of objects in your buckets are just arbitrary strings.

Comment: Thank you.

Is there a way to get the output like when we run the Athena Query to retrieve all access logs from ALB? They already separate the logs by month and day. All I want is instead of having multiple CSV files, I only want one CSV for the entire day and one CSV for the entire month.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Athena, and I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. I think this answer addresses the topic of your original question, which had to do with operating on "folders" in a bucket. For the question posed in your comment you may want to open a new question here on the site.